# Spark sql throws UTF8 String Casting Error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It seems like  Spark sql Window function does not working properly .
I am running a spark job in Hadoop Cluster where a HDFS block size is 128 MB and 
Spark Version 1.5 CDH 5.5

I am reading a avro file and doing the below operation

**My requirement:**

**If there are multiple records with same data_rfe_id then take the single record as per maximum seq_id and maxiumum service_id**

I see that in raw data there  are some records with same data_rfe_id and same seq_id so hence, I applied row_number using Window function so that I can filter the records with row_num === 1

I want to use Window Function only to achieve this .

Why is it happening like this?

Do I need to reshuffle before I apply window function on dataframe?

It throws the below exception for some tasks alone and the job failed after 4 repeated failed tasks ?

When do we get these kind of exception .

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rowNumber
 .....

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- transitional_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seq_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data_rfe_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- service_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_start_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id: string (nullable = true)


 val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(df("data_rfe_id")).orderBy(df("seq_id").desc)
  val rankDF =df.withColumn("row_num",rowNumber.over(windowFunction))
  rankDF.select("data_rfe_id","seq_id","service_id","row_num").show(200,false)
```

In my code i am not doing any casting . Just reading everything as string

I am getting the correct results when i run the above code in Spark-shell.

But if i try to run the same code from spark-submit command by supplying the jar it throws the below exception

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:  org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getInt(rows.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getInt(JoinedRow.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BoundReference.eval(BoundAttribute.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Window$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.next(Window.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Window$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.next(Window.scala:252)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could someone explain me why I am getting the above error ? and How do I resolve that ?

Comment: I read a avro file in which all columns are string  and  once I convert into dataframe, all columns also string, the only integer that comes into picture is that row_number which is a derived column

Answer (score -2):

The data in the source could have been modified and because of the datatype issue it will fail. To resolve this error you can check the data in the source and remove unnecessary files and it should work.